# Why is `ArrayList.add` causing a ConcurrentModificationException?

Tags: java, arrays, arraylist

Trying to wrap up a project. Everything works in it except it can't instantiate the animal into the designated array. This line is code that my instructor gave me, so I'm at even more of a loss. This is what I used to declare the array list:

```
private static ArrayList<Dog> dogList = new ArrayList<Dog>();
```

I then collect the information I needed and use the code below to try and add it to the array list. nthDog is a previously declared variable and the parameters are correct.

```
 Dog nthDog = new Dog(name, breed, gender, age, weight, acquisitionDate,
            acquisitionCountry, trainingStatus, reserved, inServiceCountry);
 dogList.add(nthDog);
```

This code was sent to me by my instructor, however, when used it pulls up the errors ConcurrentModificationException and checkForComodification. Can't figure out what could be wrong.

Comment: We need more code to see the cause for that sort of error, ideally to see all the places `dogList` is used, or more context around the `add` call.

Comment: random guess until then: are you adding to `dogList` while iterating over it?

Comment: `ConcurrentModificationException` requires there to be an `Iterator`, either explicitly or implicitly e.g. with a for-each loop or a copy constructor. Please can you show the code doing the iterating?

Comment: Please provide a [mre].

Answer (score 0):

You might be modifying a collection directly while it is iterating over the collection with a fail-fast iterator, the iterator will throw this exception.

For more details on ConcurrentModificationException Please refer https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/ConcurrentModificationException.html